# jetty on android is crashing

Tags: android, webserver, jetty

hey I am developing an android application and I came to a problem, I want to develop a web http server for my android application and through my research I came across this example

[Integrate Jetty Server In Your Application](http://codersapprentice.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-integrate-jetty-server-in-my.html)

and whenever I tried to run it I get this type of error that I don't know how to solve it, has any one came across this error or similar? I'm using eclipse and trying to run it on android 4.2.2 and also on 4.1.2

`05-23 12:53:18.351: D/dalvikvm(626): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-23 12:53:19.112: E/Trace(626): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-23 12:53:19.461: W/dalvikvm(626): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity$1; (641)
05-23 12:53:19.461: W/dalvikvm(626): Link of class 'Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity$1;' failed
05-23 12:53:19.461: E/dalvikvm(626): Could not find class 'com.example.jettytest.MainActivity$1', referenced from method com.example.jettytest.MainActivity.<init>
05-23 12:53:19.461: W/dalvikvm(626): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 536 (Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity$1;) in Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity;
05-23 12:53:19.461: D/dalvikvm(626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
05-23 12:53:19.471: E/dalvikvm(626): Could not find class 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server', referenced from method com.example.jettytest.MainActivity.onCreate
05-23 12:53:19.471: W/dalvikvm(626): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 640 (Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Server;) in Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity;
05-23 12:53:19.471: D/dalvikvm(626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
05-23 12:53:19.471: W/dalvikvm(626): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity$1; (641)
05-23 12:53:19.471: W/dalvikvm(626): Link of class 'Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity$1;' failed
05-23 12:53:19.471: D/dalvikvm(626): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0ff3 at 0x05 in Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity;.<init>
05-23 12:53:19.471: D/dalvikvm(626): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x10bf at 0x0c in Lcom/example/jettytest/MainActivity;.onCreate
05-23 12:53:19.481: D/AndroidRuntime(626): Shutting down VM
05-23 12:53:19.481: W/dalvikvm(626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.jettytest.MainActivity$1
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.example.jettytest.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-23 12:53:19.491: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 12:53:21.291: I/Process(626): Sending signal. PID: 626 SIG: 9`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use Jetty 7, as it is compatible with the JDK that Android uses.

(Jetty 8 uses advanced features of JDK 6 not present in Android, and Jetty 9 has a minimum requirement of JDK 7 which is too new for Android)

The error you got `Could not find class 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server'` is typically a sign that you tried to use Jetty 8/9 with Android (or more rarely, you had a packaging mistake)

You also have to replace the standard JVM classloader that Jetty uses with one that is Android compatible.

An open source example of Jetty 7 on Android can be found at the i-jetty project at [code.google.com/p/i-jetty/](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/).  The i-jetty project is maintained by the Jetty developers.